# How to call another step within an chunk process in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is the following possible/advisable with Spring Batch?

I have a csv file, say foo.csv. I set up a chunk process that reads the file into Foo objects and then processes them into Bar objects. Finally these are written into a file bars.csv.

> foos.csv ----[IR]----> Foo ---- [IP]-----> Bar ------[IW]----> bars.csv
>
> where IR stands for ItemReader, IP for ItemProcessor and IW for ItemWriter

Now I want to further process the Bar object, turn it into a Baz object and do some other stuff with it, e.g. write it into a file bazs.csv or so.

> foos.csv ----[IR]----> Foo ---- [IP 1]-----> Bar ------[IW 1]----> bars.csv
>                                                                         ---- [IP 2]-----> Baz ------[IW 2] ----> bazs.csv

Or,even better

> foos.csv ----[IR]----> Foo ---- [IP 1]-----> Bar ------[IW 1]----> bars.csv
>                                                                        ----- [IW 2] ---->[Next Step]
>
> where we repeatedly call the next step **within** the iteration, thereby passing the next Bar object. In this next step we could then do the conversion to Baz.

So in summary: Is it possible to call a step from within a chunk process? Is it a good idea? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at present you have at least 2 possible solutions

- [chaining itemprocessors](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#chainingItemProcessors), each processor can be a writer too
- use a database to hold the intermediate work and use it for future steps and/or [flows](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#controllingStepFlow)

your last usecase looks like it is better implemented with a [message oriented solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using a [CompositeItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html) to output the data from the processing step to two different sources, one to "bars.csv" and one to some sort of "Baz" ItemWriter.

Your flow will then be look like this:

```
foos.csv ---- [IR] ---> Foo --- [IP1] ---> Bar ---- [IW1] ----> bars.csv 
                                                    [IW2] ----> Baz --- [further steps]
```

Will this solve your use case?